# JRuby proc as a Java interface implementation

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, jruby-java-interop

My question is related to [closure conversion](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#closure-conversion). I want to test a proc that implements a functional interface from jruby code.

I have a simple proc like

```
proc { print 'hey!' }
```

to implement a java functional interface like

```
public void doStuff()
```

Since the client object is a Java object that is

```
public class MyClient {
    private MyInterface iface;

    public MyClient(MyInterface iface) {
        this.iface = iface;
    }

    public void doHighLevelStuff() {
        this.iface.doStuff();
    }
}
```

it works right, since jruby manages to "cast" the proc into a java functional interface. So, this part it's ok.

My problem is testing this code, calling it from jruby. I don't know how to tell jruby to treat that proc as an implementation of `MyInterface` to be able to call the actual method `doStuff` instead of the ruby specification `call`.

So, the question is how to tell jruby to treat a proc as a given java interface.

Answer (score 0):

`client = MyClient.new { print 'hey! }` and then `client.doHighLevelStuff` should work just fine ... if you have a proc instance simply pass it in (`&proc`) as a block into the constructor.